# referencing one's own class library in a F# project on VS2015

Tags: f#, visual-studio-2015, libraries

i have a solution called Algos
on Solution explorer i have 2 projects inside this solution
one called Algos (again ! maybe i should change the name for avoiding confusion ?)
which is a console application
one called MyLibrary which is a Class Library

I have in the solution explorer added in the References of the Project Algo MyLibrary and i can see it in the list.

```
// useful functions

// returns the minimum + index of the minimum
namespace Misc

exception InnerError of string
module Search =
   let mini (s : (int*int) list) = 
         match s with 
            | [] -> (-1,(-1,-1))
            | _  -> s |> Seq.mapi (fun i x -> (i, x)) |> Seq.minBy snd

   let maxi (s : (int*int) list) = 
         match s with 
            | [] -> (-1,(-1,-1))
            | _  -> s |> Seq.mapi (fun i x -> (i, x)) |> Seq.maxBy snd

module Bit = 
   let rec sumbits (n:int):int=
      let rec helper acc m =
         match m with
            | 0 -> acc
            | 1 -> acc+1 // enlever cela ?
            | _ -> let r = m%2
                   helper (acc+r) (m>>>1)
      helper 0 n

   let power2 k = 
     let powers_of_2 = [|1;2;4;8;16;32;64;128;256;512;1024;2048;4096;8192;16384;32768;65536;131072;262144;524288;1048576;2097152;4194304;8388608;16777216|]
     if ((k >= 24) || (k<0)) then raise (InnerError("power exponent not allowed"))
        else powers_of_2.[k]
```

i'm just to use Misc.Bit.power2 in the main code

```
open MyLibrary
let a = Misc.Bit.power2 3
```

but Misc.Bit will be underlined and I have a compiler error

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The value, constructor, namespace or type 'Bit' is not defined  Algos   C:\Users\Fagui\Documents\GitHub\Learning Fsharp\Algos\Algos\TSP.fs  50

what have i done wrong ? does it come from other parts of the source code perhaps ?

there are no other warnings. 
both projects use .NET Framework 4.5.2
MyLibrary uses Target F# Runtime 4.3.1 while there is no similar indication for Algos.

thanks

Comment: you probably need to change `open MyLibrary` to `open Misc` because it is a namespace where `Bit` is defined

Comment: what is the dll name and what happens if you just try to #load the .fs file? or #r the dll?

Answer (score 0):

Two things come to mind here: I don't see where the namespace `MyLibrary` is defined, and you haven't mentioned that you actually compiled the dependency.

Generally, to reference and use a library within the same solution, you need to:

- add the library to the using program's dependency, preferably via: References – right-click – add Reference (Reference Manager) – Projects – Solution, by checking the checkbox of the dependency.
- compile the dependency. When referenced properly, this should automatically occur before dependent code is compiled, but IntelliSense will only update after compiles! So hit compile when you see outdated errors.
- use identifiers from the library via their correct namespace. Make sure that the qualified names or open declarations in the using code are correct.

To my knowledge, this should be all you need to do.

There are rare cases where files get write-locked but never released on compilation and you need to restart Visual Studio to be able to compile again. I've also encountered a case where some interaction of Git and Visual Studio created corrupted, half-deleted files with effectively no file owner; this required a reboot to fix. If you're really scratching your head and the errors are clearly nonsensical, maybe try moving the folder to check for file system damage.

Comment: it still doesn't work for me, i am really scratching my head over this

Answer (score 0):

This should certainly work. Please also make sure that you target same versions of F# and .NET: .NET 4.5.2 and 4.4.0.0 in the library and the console application

[image: Solution Screenshot]